# В чем разница между чистящий и очищающий?

Tags: выбор-слова

Мне интересно в чем разница между чистящий и очищающий. Спасибо.

Comment: Специально не смотрел в словари, чтобы не поддаваться влиянию. Разница в абстрактности смысла. "Чистящий" это приземлённое, по отношению к материальному. "Очищающий" это в любом абстрактном смысле - духовность, честь/репутация, и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

`Чистяший` - able to clean, that is to remove some contamination. Accent is on the process.
`Очищающий` - able to **make** clean. Accent is on the result.

Answer (score 3):

Чистящие средства (обычно порошки), чистящий карандаш для оптики, картридж для бритвы - то, чем нужно производить механические действия: скрести, тереть, то есть жестко чистить в буквальном смысле.

Очищающий гель (для лица), аэрозоль (для воздуха), лосьон, суп - что-то более щадящее, то, что действует не сразу, не механически и само по себе не обладает чистящими свойствами, а только в совокупности с чем-то (процессами кожи, тела, распределяясь по воздуху).

Comment: Я абсолютно согласна с @clever-masha, разница в значениях точно подмечена.

Answer (score 0):

Чистящий означает то, что чистит. Возможно не до конца, только частично.

Очищающий означает то, что очищает. Очищает полностью, но возможно до определенной степени.